# Firefox: disable “send link/tab to device”

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 56.0.2 64bit on Arch Linux, I don't like contextual menu options:

- send tab to a device, while on a tab
- send link to a device, while on a link

How can I disable them?

**UPDATE**: following @ipor-sircer (I asked on Unix forum before, then I moved the question here) answer, I tried his suggestion (use **S3 Menu Wizard** firefox extension) but I'm looking for a different way to reach the goal.
Anyway that wasn't a waste of time:
Maybe, is there a way to use the userChrome.css file and integrate the content which I want to *block*?

S3 extension created a file with this inside:

```
{"context_sendTabToDevice":true,"context-castvideo":true,"context-sendpagetodevice":true,"context-sendlinktodevice":true}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you'd have to type this on userChrome.css
The first class removes the actual command, and the second of each line remove the separator so that it doesn't look like there is something missing on the context menu.

```
#context_sendTabToDevice, #context_sendTabToDevice_separator  {display: none !important;}

#context-sendpagetodevice, #context-sep-sendpagetodevice  {display: none !important;}

#contentAreaContextMenu #context-sendlinktodevice,
#contentAreaContextMenu #context-sep-sendlinktodevice {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thx a bunch

Comment: thank a lot, it works! I want to add that I have had to create the above-mentioned file (user***C***hrome.css) and the containing folder too (***c***hrome) inside my profile directory. Credits goes to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1942278&p=11772727#post11772727

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it, you can also simply deactivate the Firefox Accounts feature altogether, which will remove said menu entry as well as the login prompt in the main menu.

For this open the [configuration editor](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) by browsing to `about:config` and set the entry `identity.fxaccounts.enabled` to `false` by double clicking it.